# Mellanox MT27500 Link to Port 1 is Down

Tags: linux-networking, mellanox

I have Mellanox MT27500 dual port card which is installed on HP SL250s. Ubuntu 14.04.5 with 3.13.0-24-generic kernel is running on the server. Both port1 type and port 2 type are defined as eth. I have connected port 1 and port 2 to switch with same type of cable but only port 2 seems linked. Led belongs to port 1 is off.

Do you have any idea to use both ports?

```
$ sudo lspci | grep Mellanox
07:00.0 Network controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27500 Family [ConnectX-3]

$ cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:07\:00.0/mlx4_port1
eth
$ cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:07\:00.0/mlx4_port2
eth

$ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
  Supported ports: [ TP ]
  Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
  Supported pause frame use: No
  Supports auto-negotiation: No
  Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
  Advertised pause frame use: No
  Advertised auto-negotiation: No
  Speed: Unknown!
  Duplex: Unknown! (255)
  Port: Twisted Pair
  PHYAD: 0
  Transceiver: internal
  Auto-negotiation: off
  MDI-X: Unknown
  Supports Wake-on: d
  Wake-on: d
  Current message level: 0x00000014 (20)
        link ifdown
  Link detected: no

$ sudo ethtool eth1
Settings for eth1:
  Supported ports: [ TP ]
  Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
  Supported pause frame use: No
  Supports auto-negotiation: No
  Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
  Advertised pause frame use: No
  Advertised auto-negotiation: No
  Speed: Unknown!
  Duplex: Unknown! (255)
  Port: Twisted Pair
  PHYAD: 0
  Transceiver: internal
  Auto-negotiation: off
  MDI-X: Unknown
  Supports Wake-on: g
  Wake-on: g
  Current message level: 0x00000014 (20)
        link ifdown
  Link detected: no

$ sudo ip link set dev eth0 up
$ sudo ip link set dev eth1 up

$ ip link show eth0
12: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state   DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:02:c9:fc:25:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
$ ip link show eth1
13: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:02:c9:fc:25:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Which switch are you using?

Comment: @Thomas Both ports are connected to 10G ports on Brocade ICX6450.

Comment: Did you already try to switch the cables to check if the cables are OK? Second would be to only switch one side of the cable connection, e.g. on the switch side to check if the switch port is affected. Also check the switch configuration, maybe the port is not configured or has another misconfiguration.